# How do I access USB storage on android device in react-native?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-cli

I'm creating an application which to be play on my android device. After several weeks searching and continue to develop the application logic, I still unable to find a way to access USB device.

I'm develop using **React-Native CLI** and device is running on **Nougat 7.1.2**.

Application will be run on a device as below:-
[image]

At application startup, it will check the target selected either local folder or removable drive. If user select removable drive, it should be find any existing removable drive and get all files inside it that having images and video to be play (like screen saver/ slideshow) on main screen.

I've come across [USB OTG Storage](https://github.com/scizers/react-native-otg-storage) library, but I'm not understand how to access the USB storage content as the console show any difference log between USB Drive and USB Dongle for Mouse.
[image: Metro Server Console]

If I'm unmounted and mounted both at several times, both device log will trigger same '***USB DISK 2.0***'
[image]

Is there any other library/packages that able to search for removable drive storage and access it's files?

Comment: Doesn't ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE show the drive?

Comment: @blackapps I'm not familiar with that. I search for the term just now, does it available on react-native CLI? It's look like Android Studio activity.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @WadeBaird, my way to tackle this might not best to be heard. I'm having trouble in react-native. Though, I change my platform from React-native CLI to Xamarin.Forms to access the storage. I handle it like the same I develop using Desktop Application style.